# Window width detection in Ext.js using Ext.getBody.getViewSize()

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, extjs5

I am sizing a window based on the Browser Window. For now I am using Ext.getBody.getViewSize as an approximation for this. It is working in FireFox and Chrome, but not IE.

```
Ext.define('MyProject.view.MyWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.myWindow',
id: 'myWindow',
width : '70%',
height: '80%',
layout : 'fit',
title: 'My Window',
bodyStyle: {
    maxHeight: '700px'
},
   listeners:{
    resize:function() {
        console.log('resize');
        var size = Ext.getBody().getViewSize();
        console.log('height = ' + size.height );
        console.log('width = ' + size.width );
        this.setHeight(.9 * size.height );
        this.setWidth(.8 * size.width );
        this.alignTo(this.container, 'c-c');
        console.log('new height = ' + size.height );
        console.log('new width = ' + size.width );
    },
    afterrender:function() {
        console.log('afterrender');
        console.log(Ext.getBody());
        var size = Ext.getBody().getViewSize();
        console.log('height = ' + size.height );
        console.log('width = ' + size.width );

        this.setHeight(.9 * size.height );
        this.setWidth(.8 * size.width );
        this.alignTo(this.container, 'c-c');
        console.log('new height = ' + size.height );
        console.log('new width = ' + size.width );

    }
},
initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

The height and width doesn't change if I resize the IE browser window, but changes if I resize a Chrome or Firefox window.
Is there another way to get the browser window size using Ext.js 5 that works in IE?

Comment: The sample doesn't really make sense. You're listening for the resize of the window, then trying to set a new size which should trigger another resize. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want the window to fill up 80% of the width and *0% of the height in all browsers without using Viewport. When I try to change this to Viewport, I am getting many compilation errors. This is close to working, except in IE.

Comment: Do you know why screen width or window width would be calculated different for IE than Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: A grid stops working in Viewport.

Comment: The application already has a Viewport. This is a child window for performing a task, so I am hoping I don't have to create another Viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at using Ext.Viewport instead. You can then call getWidth and getHeight on this.

See the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport

Comment: Using Viewport was resulting in errors for the initialization of elements within the window.

Comment: Can you share some more code, like what layout are you using for your main view, etc

Comment: MyWindow has children using table layout.

Comment: It turned out I could solve my problem (getting a window to be appropriately sized) by using the Border layout, and autowidth and autoheight to get the window to be correctly sized. Thank you!